# Why do these bars look different in PageSpeed?

Tags: html, pagespeed

Maybe my question is basic but why when entering some pages in PageSpeed ​​Insights you can see percentage bars of different colors and in some other pages not?
Is it because of lazy loading?
I have an idea but I would like to know more specifically, if someone could explain it to me it would be very kind, thank you
[These are the percentage bars that appear on some pages and do not appear on others.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rqp3q.png)

Comment: **what** looks different **compared to what**? It's unclear what your question actually is.

Comment: "PageSpeed ​​Insights you can see percentage bars of different colors and in some other pages not?" - those bars appear on all reports for me - perhaps you have the details region collapsed?

Comment: test on pages like this http://lpolatam.com/